# Return the number of times the string "hello/HELLO/hellO ..." appears anywhere in the given string

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

> Return the number of times the string "hello/Hello/...etc" appears anywhere in the given string.
>
> The different in the problem is that
>
> The string hello can be in any case i.e either  upper case or lower case.

**Sample Input #1**
count("abc hello def")

**Sample Output #1**
1

**Sample Input #2**
count("Hi. Hello. Hello. Ok")

**Sample Output #2**

2

**Sample Input #3**

count("hi")

**Sample Output #3**

0

**MyApproach**

```
public int count(String str)
    {
      String str1="Hello";

        int l=str.length();
        int l1=str1.length();
        if(l<l1)
        {
         return 0;
        }
        else
        {
           int count=0;
           int p=0;
           int j=0;
           while(j<l)
           {
            char c=str.charAt(j);
            char c1=str1.charAt(p);
            if(c==c1)
             {
               p++;

               if(p==l1)
               {
                count++;
                p=0;
               }  

             }
             else
             {
                 p=0;
             }
             j++;

           } 

     return count;
    }

}

Output       TestcaseParameters Testcase Actual Answer  Expected

No output    'HELLO how are you'               0             1
```

I am getting the following output.

> Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @RileyCarney `contains` will not help in getting the count.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Occurrences of substring in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string)

Comment: Is the `+ 32` and `- 32` logic intended to handle upper case vs. lower case? You could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320200/turn-a-user-input-string-to-upper-case-java to get a better way to do that.

Comment: I have updated my code.The only difference is  the pattern of string which I need to find can be in any case.

Comment: @YassinHajaj I have updated my code.

Comment: @Marvin I think it isn't because of case sensitive nature of the pattern to be found.

Comment: @Jasonarora: Wasn't clear to me in the first version. But couldn't you convert all to lowercase and use one of the methods from the other question?

Comment: @Marvin Yes Marwin that would be much better.Thanku for the hint.

Answer (score 6):

I'm wondering how your code compiles. c1 is not even declared. I would probably use such logic:

```
str1.toUpperCase().split(str2.toUpperCase).length()-1
```

The code above does not return correct answer when `str1` beginsWith or endsWith `str2`. Here is a better version:

```
public static int count(String str1, String str2) {
    int count = 0;
    int len1 = str1.length();
    int len2 = str2.length();
    for (int i=0;i<=len1-len2;++i){
        if ((str1.substring(i,i+len2)).equalsIgnoreCase(str2)) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The code moves `str2` rightwards once a step, and compares if `str2` is the same as the substring of `str1`. Please note in the situation `str1` = "AAA", and `str2` = "AA", the result is 2, since both the first and the second occurrences of `AA` will have a match.
Step 1:

```
str1: *****
str2: **
```

Step 2:

```
str1: *****
str2:  **
```

Step 3:

```
str1: *****
str2:   **
```

Step 4:

```
str1: *****
str2:    **
```

If you wish in the above situation, `AA` only counts once, here is the code for you:

```
public static int count(String str1, String str2) {
    int count = 0;
    int len1 = str1.length();
    int len2 = str2.length();
    for (int i=0;i<=len1-len2;){
        if ((str1.substring(i,i+len2)).equalsIgnoreCase(str2)) {
            ++count;
            i+=len2;
        }else{
            ++i;
        }

    }
    return count;
}
```

This version above works this way:

Step 1:

```
str1: *****
str2: **
```

Step 2:

```
str1: *****
str2:   **
```

It will not compare any character already compared in the previous steps.

I tested the code against your sample input data, and they all return the expected results.

Comment: I upvoted you but this is not correct at all actually and I think it should be edited. The result could differ if hello is at the beginning or at the end or in the middle only.

Comment: Thanks @YassinHajaj. This is some pseudo code off the top of my head. I will edit and refine it.

Comment: No problem. But it was smart :).

Comment: @ElgsQianChen I have updated my code.Sir,Can you tell me what error I did.As I will keep your code for reference.

Comment: Thanks @YassinHajaj. I edited my answer and made a more serious version.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a school assignment then pls say so.
Otherwise You will need to ask a question on google like:
'count occurrences in string java' or something.
This will give you - tada - stackoverflow:

[Occurrences of substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string)

Hope to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty intuitive solution :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(count("hellohellohellohihihihihihihellohihhihello")); // Prints : 5
}

public static int count(String str){
    String str1 = "hello";
    String str2 = str.toLowerCase();
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (true){
        if (str2.contains(str1)){
            count++;
            str2 = str2.substring(str2.indexOf(str1) + str1.length(), str2.length());
        } else {
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

//in this we have changed every upper case character in lowercase for comparing it with s2
public int count(String str){
        String s1="";String s2="hello"; int l2=s2.length(); int count=0;

```
    int l1=str.length();
    for(int i=0;i<=l1-l2;i++){
        for(int j=i;j<l2+i;j++){
            char ch=str.charAt(j);
            if(ch>=65&&ch<=90){
                ch=(char)(ch+32);
                s1=s1+ch;
            }
            else
            s1=s1+ch;
        }
        if(s1.equals(s2)){
            count++;
        }
//in that line i have removed the data of string s1 to form new string again
           s1="";
    }return count;

}
```